# Rate limiting requests to a 3rd-party API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, request, rate-limiting

My code:

```
const limit = require('simple-rate-limiter')
const request = limit(require('request').defaults({
    gzip: true
})).to(15).per(10 * 1000) // 15 requests per 10 seconds

request(API_ENDPOINT, callback) // call API thousands of times
```

Libraries: [simple-rate-limiter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-rate-limiter) and the well-known [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) library.

---

I need to call a 3rd-party API thousands of times that only allows 15 requests every 10 seconds. The above code doesn't limit my requests correctly so the server sends a `429 Too Many Requests` HTTP status code.

I can send 15 requests at once but then the program will have to wait for 10 seconds before it can send any more requests or it'll get a `429` response again.

I think this is because the connection to the server takes anywhere from hundreds of milliseconds to few seconds (`300ms-2s`). So my request time is different from the time the server receives the request.

Responses from the server contain a `Date` header. Can that be use somehow to limit the requests correctly? Is there a library that makes this easy? Even after implementing correct rate limiting, if you get a `429` response, is there a simple way to retry that too?

Comment: you want to trick an API and to call endpoint more than it's limits? did i get you right?

Comment: No, I want to call it according to the limits. If I don't do that I get a `429`  HTTP response which I don't want to get.

Answer (score 0):

OK so the approach is to check how much time has passed from the start till the end of call. I will assume that it is safe to call API every 667 milliseconds.

```
var startTime,
    endTime;

function timeDiff() {
    return (endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime());
}
function startRequest() {
    startTime = new Date();
    request(API_ENDPOINT, requestCallback)
}
function requestCallback(data) {
   //do what you please with data
   endTime = new Date();  
   var diff = timeDiff(); 
   if(diff < 667) {
        //To early to start API, need to wait.
        setTimeout(startRequest, 667 - diff);
   } else {
        //It is fine to start request now.
        setTimeout(startRequest);
   }
}

startRequest();
```

This code will keep calling API as soon as the call is finished unless it finished faster than 667 milliseconds.